# What does this notation represent

Tags: notation

$${\bf w}_{k}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,{\bf Q})$$

Note that $\bf Q$ is $2\times2$ matrix. So what is ${\bf w}_k$?

This is from [Wikipedia- Kalman example application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application.2C_technical)

Comment: From the tag description: **Please remember to mention where (book, paper, webpage, etc.) you encountered any mathematical notation you are asking about.**

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Multivariate normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Notation_and_parametrization)

Comment: ... centred at $0$ with covariance matrix $\bf Q$